# Handle exception thrown somewhere in a task continuation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, task-parallel-library

What is the best way to handle exceptions thrown somewhere in a task continuation?

For example, I have a simple task continuation below (`updateMessages` -> `updateInterface`) but in reality this could be a chain of more than 2 tasks.  I want to have a generic exception "catch all" task which continues from any fault which could occur in the chain.

How I'm doing this is by defining an `Action` (which observes and logs the exception) and continuing from each task with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` set.  Is there perhaps a better way of doing this?

```
Task updateMessages = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Do stuff
});

Task updateInterface = updateMessages.ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    // UI updates
  }, 
  System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, 
  TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Action<Task> failureAction = new Action<Task>(failedTask =>
{
    // Observe and log exceptions
});

updateMessages.ContinueWith(failureAction, CancellationToken.None,
                            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
updateInterface.ContinueWith(failureAction, CancellationToken.None,          
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, 
                             TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is the approach I use, and it works well.

A couple of asides that aren't about the question:

- Does your failureAction really need to run on the main UI thread?
- I'd write a helper method to attach the failure continuation since you're going to be doing this with every task.

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be on the UI thread unless some control update is required.  The helper method is a good idea.  Thanks :)

Comment: Great.  In that case, I would say don't have it always be scheduled on the ui thread (since that costs extra), and rather, if the control needs to update a control, invoke using that control.  (It's a minor point since we are only talking about the case of a fault anyways).